# Recommend a c library calculating the product of two sparse matrix(size: 100000*100000)

Tags: c, matrix

The matrix is so large`(size: 100000*100000)` which consume two much, so the library should  use triplet or other way to store it. I search the Internet, but those library always  use `common matrix` not `triplet` or other way to `compress the storage`.

It didn't work for me. Can someone recommend some `c library` for me?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is this the only thing you need to do with the matrices? If so then it might be worth just coding it yourself...

Comment: I'm developing a software about crawler. I don't want to invent every wheel again. I'm sorry. I will try my best to code myself but time is limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [Boost - Compressed Sparse Matrix](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix_sparse.htm#21Description) an alternative for you?

EDIT:
Pure C-Library: [CSparse](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/c_src/csparse/csparse.html)

Comment: I'm afraid I can only use c library.

Comment: then maybe http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/c_src/csparse/csparse.html
it uses compressed-column or triplet form for storage.

Comment: @pokey909: Excellent link. Add it to your answer and I suspect it'll be the accepted one.